# How to convert an array of complex numbers into real within flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, complex-numbers

I was wondering if there is way of converting lists with complex numbers into list with real numbers.

`[3.084580633850594 + 0.0i, 0.03930937672422563 + 0.0i, 25958.26505623091 + 0.0i, 28566.521479745476 + 0.0i]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way in which i did it was by using.

```
for (var item in list){
  double real = item.real;
}
```

https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/my_complex/latest/my_complex/Complex/real.html

Comment: Been a while I am very sorry for not replying. Thanks very much.

Comment: can you recheck the link, is it https://pub.dev/documentation/quantity/latest/number/Complex-class.html?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing list of complex numbers using some appropriate `Complex` number class, using [`List.map`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) would be neater:

```
var realParts = complexNumbers.map((z) => z.real);
```

Note that that will give you an `Iterable`; if you want a `List`, you'll need to call [`Iterable.toList`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/Iterable/toList.html):

```
var realParts = complexNumbers.map((z) => z.real).toList();
```